# wpf ItemsControl binding problem

Tags: wpf, binding

I bind to a ItemsControl in my codebehind:

```
ColumnVisibilityItems.DataContext = gc.ColumnVisibility;
```

where ColumnVisibility is a ObservableCollection, also tried it with dictionary..

my markup

```
                <ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnVisibilityItems">
                    <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                </ItemsControl>
```

while stepping through, i see the collection bound having 11 items. but ItemsControl renders only the first item in collection.

Is ItemsSource property necessary to be set for this to work? because whenever i try to set that in code behind, i get the exception saying items cannot be modified because they exist already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically you need to specify your Template. See [the msdn docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx) for a fuller example

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="ColumnVisibilityItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: i thought so, and actually tried messing with ItemTemplate, but it didn't seem to make a big difference. For example this code, produces one empty item... 
am i setting the binding incorrectly in codebehind?

Comment: i've updated my example to show how you would set ItemsSource, which is probably what you need